# Need to integrate LUIS.ai to a flow in power automate

Tags: azure-language-understanding, power-automate

After creating an app within LUIS.ai that accurately predicts the intent of a text input, we tried exporting its functionality to a power automate flow. We want LUIS.ai to return the prediction taking into account an emails body as the parameter, however since it is not in JSON format LUIS.ai always returns an error. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of the error you are getting? Also, you can report your issue with the screenshots of the steps and error in preview.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/support to get help if the issue is related to power automate. Check the data which LUIS is receiving, there must be some invalid data which is not qualifying as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to create an Azure Function with the email as the input and prediction as the output. You can then write a function to identify the email body (if it's not already available in Flow), parse it into the correct JSON format for LUIS, and call the LUIS API. Then all you need to do is [create a custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/april19/microsoft-flow/connect-azure-services-custom-connectors).

Edit: LUIS service can be called via GET request. I think you should be able to do this with a POST passing the parameters as application/x-www-form-urlencoded values. But if you're using a Flow Connector for LUIS it's probably already taking care of this for you... For reference, the URL to call the API is `https://{endpoint}/luis/v2.0/apps/{appId}?q={q}`.

Comment: Ok, right now I am not sure how to go about this; As of right now I have the trigger for every new email that arrives. Once that arrives, I have the get prediction set up and the utterance text is the body of the email. This is what is continually causing errors. I am missing a step between the trigger and get prediction. Which Azure Function do I need to solve this?

Comment: Azure Function would be a coded solution. It sounds like there might already be connectors in Flow for parsing email and calling LUIS? If so, I know there are Flow actions you can use to parse and manipulate text, though without a similar setup myself I'm unable to say exactly what you would need to do to parse it. If you can pass the body to an intermediate step, you should be able to figure out how to create a JSON request. I've added the format for the LUIS request to my answer in case you need it.

Comment: Actually, I checked and it's usually just a GET request with a JSON response. Changing my edit.

Comment: Is there a way to send a screenshot? I think it would help show the issue at hand.